# How to incorporate Siri in React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have a react native iOS app in which I have to get/record user voice query and respond to that.

Now the thing is that I want this feature 'Interaction Less'. Like I don't want how ChatGPT mobile app did it. Like they had a headphone button, I press it, record my query and get answer. I don't want like this.

I want it 'Interaction Less' like we have Siri. Even if my iPhone is on side of the table and I say 'Hey Siri', it will start listening me. I want it like this.

So thinking to do it like this: Like user will say 'Hey {AppName}' and voice assistant of my app should start listening me.

Also thinking to do it via Siri because if my app went in background state [Auto-locked], even then I want my voice assistant to listen me.

Trying to figure out some way to implement this. But unable to find any way.

Can somebody guide me, how can I implement above thing in my ReactNative iOS app.

P.S: 'Interaction Less' means that phone shouldn't be in his hand. It can be in his pocket or on the side of the table.

Looking for documentation/guidance of how to incorporate Siri in React Native iOS app, to perform some functionality in my app through voice.